# Горячие клавиши в xcode

Tags: xcode

кто подскажет - есть ли возможность переключаться между открытыми проектами с клавиатуры?   искал в горячих клавишах - не нашел. очень неудобно тыкать мышкой в меню и там выбирать окна.  
спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> для переключении между окнами любого osx приложения